# Ocean Petrel PluginPackager Fails Third-Party Validation

Tags: ocean, petrel

I'm developing a Petrel plugin via Ocean, both versions 2022, but when running the PluginPackager as part of the post-build of the PIP project, validation fails:

```
2>  ERROR Plugin includes library that is already distributed by Petrel or another plugin, but it is not identical.
2>  Plugin includes tbb, which conflicts with the same library in .
```

The error doesn't tell me which library but there are only three other instances of tbb.dll in the Petrel installation and various plugins, ***none*** of which are the same version as the tbb.dll I'm using.

According to the AcceptanceChecklist.xml, it seems that there should not be a validation error:

> The plug-in may use 3rd party libraries deployed by Petrel. The Components list documents this set of 3rd parties.
>
> - The plug-in must not deploy any library on this list, unless a different version is required

Does anyone know how to pass validation when deploying third-party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

To pass the validations and generate the .pip you should follow some rules that was useful for me:

- The \bin where are located the .dlls does not have contain any SLB dll.
- So the SLB dlls referenced should be marked wih CopyLocal = false.
- In the DeployList.xml file you don't include any SLB dll.
- If you use some 3rd party dll already used by Petrel, mark that dlls in the pip builder with the waive in the PluginPackager:
  /waiveValidationErrors="myFirstDllToBeIgnoredInTheValidation.dll | mySecondDllToBeIgnoredInTheValidation.dll"
- Be sure to use the last PluginPackager version, because it gives you more information about the exceptions.
- I use this optional parameters:
  ContinueOnError="false" IgnoreExitCode="false".
- To avoid 3rd party dll version conflicts, I use ILRepack to merge my dlls and the 3rd party in 1 unique dll. This will solve the half of your problems.